Triple comparison of cohomology in algebraic geometry
Let $X$ be a smooth proper variety over $\mathbb{Q}$ and $p$ a prime number. For an integer $k$, we have:

a finitely-generated abelian group $H^k(X^{\mathrm{an}}(\mathbb{C});\mathbb{Z})$
a finitely-generated $\mathbb{Z}_p$-module $H^k_{\mathrm{\acute{e}t}}(X_{\overline{\mathbb{Q}}};\mathbb{Z}_p)$ with $G_{\mathbb{Q}}$-action
a finite-dimensional filtered $\mathbb{Q}$-vector space $H^k_{\mathrm{dR}}(X)$

and comparison isomorphisms

$a \colon H^k(X^{\mathrm{an}}(\mathbb{C});\mathbb{Z}) \otimes_{\mathbb{Z}} \mathbb{Z}_p \to H^k_{\mathrm{\acute{e}t}}(X_{\overline{\mathbb{Q}}};\mathbb{Z}_p)$ by SGA4 exp XI thm 4.4
$b \colon H^k_{\mathrm{\acute{e}t}}(X_{\overline{\mathbb{Q}}};\mathbb{Z}_p) \otimes_{\mathbb{Z}_p} B_{\mathrm{dR}} \to H^k_{\mathrm{dR}}(X) \otimes_{\mathbb{Q}} B_{\mathrm{dR}}$ as described in Theorem 2.11 of https://webusers.imj-prg.fr/~wieslawa.niziol/final-version-open.pdf
$c \colon H^k_{\mathrm{dR}}(X) \otimes_{\mathbb{Q}} \mathbb{C} \to H^k(X^{\mathrm{an}}(\mathbb{C});\mathbb{Z}) \otimes_{\mathbb{Z}} \mathbb{C}$ by integration of differential forms

Composing $a$ and $b$, we get a map
$$
H^k(X^{\mathrm{an}}(\mathbb{C});\mathbb{Z}) \otimes_{\mathbb{Z}} B_{\mathrm{dR}} \xrightarrow{b \circ (a \otimes_{\mathbb{Z}_p} B_{\mathrm{dR}})} H^k_{\mathrm{dR}}(X) \otimes_{\mathbb{Q}} B_{\mathrm{dR}}
$$
Tensoring $c$ with $B_{\mathrm{dR}}$ over $\mathbb{Q}$, we get a map
$$
(H^k_{\mathrm{dR}}(X) \otimes_{\mathbb{Q}} B_{\mathrm{dR}}) \otimes_{\mathbb{Q}} \mathbb{C}
\cong
(H^k_{\mathrm{dR}}(X) \otimes_{\mathbb{Q}} \mathbb{C}) \otimes_{\mathbb{Q}} B_{\mathrm{dR}}
\xrightarrow{c \otimes_{\mathbb{Q}} B_{\mathrm{dR}}}
(H^k(X^{\mathrm{an}}(\mathbb{C});\mathbb{Z}) \otimes_{\mathbb{Z}} \mathbb{C})  \otimes_{\mathbb{Q}} B_{\mathrm{dR}}
$$
Putting it all together, we have an automorphism
$$
(H^k(X^{\mathrm{an}}(\mathbb{C});\mathbb{Z}) \otimes_{\mathbb{Z}} (\mathbb{C}  \otimes_{\mathbb{Q}} B_{\mathrm{dR}})
\xrightarrow{(c \otimes_{\mathbb{Q}} B_{\mathrm{dR}}) \circ (b \circ (a \otimes_{\mathbb{Z}_p} B_{\mathrm{dR}})) \otimes_{\mathbb{Q}} \mathbb{C}} (H^k(X^{\mathrm{an}}(\mathbb{C});\mathbb{Z}) \otimes_{\mathbb{Z}} (\mathbb{C}  \otimes_{\mathbb{Q}} B_{\mathrm{dR}}).
$$
Is this automorphism the identity? If not, how bad can it be? What subring of $\mathbb{C}  \otimes_{\mathbb{Q}} B_{\mathrm{dR}}$ is it defined over?
It presumably fixes cycle/Chern classes (and therefore conjecturally all absolute Hodge classes) by compatibility between the above comparison isomorphisms with cycle/Chern classes. But does it fix everything?
Similar question for arbitrary smooth $X$ or over an arbitrary number field. One could similarly ask this for a (Voevodksy) motive, but it should be equivalent.

Intuition, perhaps misguided: Aren't you secretly choosing two embeddings $\overline{\mathbf{Q}}\hookrightarrow \mathbf{C}$ and $\overline{\mathbf{Q}}\hookrightarrow \overline{\mathbf{Q}}_p$ on which these isomorphisms depend? If you then change one but not the other, wouldn't your composition change?

@PiotrAchinger true but we can still ask about the transcendence dimension of the field generated by the matrix entries

See the paper 'p-adic Betti lattices' by Y. Andre. The transcendence dimension is not independent of choices in general.

Keerthi's comment is spot on and IMO should be posted as an answer.
